# python's logical error

Tags: python

i've written this simple code, i think that it doesn't contain gramatical error but it doesn't execute so i think that thare is somewhere a logical error :o, so please i need help !! someone can save me ?! :D

```
class NumberGenerator:
"""A simple class that contains functions to generate ranges of numbers"""

@classmethod
def generate(quantity, value=[]):
    while quantity: value.append(quantity) ; quantity -= 1
    return value

class Figure:
"""Abstract class for geometric figures"""

def init(self, name):
    """This is the constructor"""
    self._name = name

def name(self):
    return self._name

class Rectangle(Figure):
"""Rectangle figure"""

def init(self, width, height):
    Figure.__init__("rectangle")
    self._width = width
    self._height = height

def width(self):
    return self.width

def height(self):
    return self.height

def size(self):
    self.width() * self.height()

if __name__ == "__main__":
# We print the range(10,0,-1)
print NumberGenerator.generate(10)
# We print the range(20,0,-1)
print NumberGenerator.generate(20)

# We create a rectangle
r = Rectangle(10, 20)
print r.size()

# EOF
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't execute"?

Comment: What's the error message? You know that whitespace is significant in python, don't you? All methods of a class should be indented.

Comment: The section "while quantity: value.append(quantity) ; quantity -= 1
" looks a bit suspicious, why don't you put it on separate lines, properly indented like the rest, just to test it.

Comment: @Ewald no it works, my error with this method (generate)that i must put self as first argument like that : 'def generate(self, quantity):
        value=[]
        while quantity: value.append(quantity) ; quantity -= 1
        return value'

Comment: Ah, see, it's been a while since I did Python - my apologies!

Answer (score 4):

Indentation aside, two errors are right here:

```
def width(self):
    return self.width

def height(self):
    return self.height
```

This should read:

```
def width(self):
    return self._width

def height(self):
    return self._height
```

Also, constructors should be called `__init__` and not `init`.

Finally, the `generate()` method has several issues:

- You probably meant to say `@staticmethod` and not `@classmethod` (class methods should take an implicit first argument, which your method doesn't).
- The loop is unnecessary (a simple `range()` call can do the trick).
- The method has a subtle bug in it, whereby the second argument (`value`) is preserved across  calls to `generate()`. If you must extend `value`, move `value = []` into the body of the method.

Comment: yeah mabe, but it's not the principal problem, cause the error appeared at the consol is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace_python\deuxiemeTest\src\com\test\deuxiemetest\oobugs.py", line 40, in <module>
    print NumberGenerator.generate(10)
  File "C:\workspace_python\deuxiemeTest\src\com\test\deuxiemetest\oobugs.py", line 8, in generate
    while quantity: value.append(quantity) ; quantity -= 1
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @slimoss And who is supposed to read that? Please put that in your question so that the format is preserved.

Comment: yeah i nkow but i'm beginner with pithon so :D and thank you for your answers :))

Answer (score 2):

Your first error message is `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'` from `NumberGenerator.generate` due to no `self` as the first argument and it is then creating the variable `quantity` as an instance of `NumberGenerator`.

Once you fix that, your next error is in the fact that `init()` should actually be `__init__()`, and once you fix that you have a further error, but I will leave that exercise to yourself.